# Problem deploying django project that uses python extdirect

Tags: django, apache, extjs, mod-wsgi, ext-direct

I am trying to deploy on Apache with mod_wsgi a Django project that uses [extdirect](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/extdirect) app.

extdirect app allows to use ExtJS Ext.Direct functionality with Django. Among other things, using custom template tags, it automatically adds to my templates lines like

```
<script type="text/javascript"> Ext.Direct.addProvider({"url": "/extdirect/MyRouter/", "namespace": "Remote", "type": "remoting", "id": "MyRouter", "actions": {"MyRouter": [{"name": "getTree", "len": 1}]}}); </script>
```

In this lines, the "url" parameter is automatically set to begin with "/extdirect"

But the problem is that I mount my site at sub URL

```
WSGIScriptAlias /mysite /usr/local/django/mysite/apache/django.wsgi
```

so the "url" from the above script does not work anymore.

The url is set in [extdirect/django/templatetags/direct_providers.py](https://github.com/iancmcc/extdirect/blob/master/extdirect/django/templatetags/direct_providers.py) file and if I manually change the code to have

```
klass, '/mysite/extdirect/%s/' % name, ns).render())
```

it works again.

**But is there any way to get it working without interfering with extdirect package?**

Comment: add to urls.py a new url that redirect /extdirect/MyRoute to /mysite/extdirect/....

Comment: This cannot help I think. The point is that my JavaScript makes request to `/extdirect` url and Apache tries to search it at the root, giving `File does not exist: /var/www/extdirect` error. It never reaches the mod.wsgi script...

Answer (score 0):

This link will probably help you without ExtJS. [Apache-django-mod-wsgi](http://blog.stannard.net.au/2010/12/11/installing-django-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-10-04/).

Comment: I know how to deploy Django on mod_wsgi, everything works but this '/extdirect' url. The guide you posted uses `WSGIScriptAlias /` so it will not work for me - I mount my app on sub-URL `/mysite`

Comment: But anyway, the guide you posted is very good guide to django deployment on mod_wsgi, I will bookmark it ;-)